# Shouldn't "Wednesday last" be "last Wednesday"?

Tags: adjectives, adverbs, word-order

In the following sentence

> I have not seen him since Wednesday last.

How is last used?

I think it should be

> I have not seen him since last Wednesday.

Comment: https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/12152/meaning-of-tuesday-last-and-monday-week

Answer (score 1):

The question was answered in the comments:

> "I have not seen him since Wednesday last" is grammatical but a bit poetical. The second sentence would usually be used. -  Weather Vane

It's old-fashioned or poetic.

> if someone used "Wednesday last" in conversation thinking that was a normal way to say "last Wednesday," they'd still be very wrong.  – the-baby-is-you